# Screen jumps from purple to black on startup and system doesn't boot up

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, graphics

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm sure this has been answered before so please accept my apologies if I'm being obtuse.

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Windows 7 machine with a view to dual-booting until I'm comfortable enough with Ubuntu to bin off Windows altogether, but I'm hitting a problem which I'm struggling to resolve.

I've done some research already and what I seem to have discovered is that I need to edit the Grub kernel to add "nomodeset" as a temporary fix to enable startup to complete (after keying ctrl+X), but then I have to add graphics drivers as a permanent solution.

I've managed to do the temporary fix but I'm struggling to understand what graphics drivers I need. I keep seeing references to NVIDIA but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to deduce from this. My machine is an Acer Aspire 5733Z laptop which has Intel Graphics and Media installed.

How do I work out what graphics drivers I need? Do I need NVIDIA ones and if so, which ones and where do I get them from? At the moment, yes I can get a screen up and run a Ubuntu session but the graphics are all squashed and every time I reboot I have to do the same temporary fix.

I'd be very grateful if anyone out there can assist me.

Many thanks.
Steve.

Thanks KAA7. I had to look up how to enter what you asked (found it was CTRL+ALT+T, something else I've learnt!) and this is the result:
[sudo] password for steve: 
    product: Aspire 5733Z (Calpella_CRB)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3050 [size=8]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

Interestingly since logging this question, but before checking if anyone had responded, I tried rebooting in Ubuntu several times last night and each time got a different result. This morning, again before checking for a response, I tried booting up. I didn't do a temporary edit of "nomodeset" and yet my laptop booted up successfully, with no flipflopping between purple and black screens and the display seems to be absolutely fine. I'm concluding therefore (at the moment anyway) that Ubuntu is happy with my installed graphics.
Many thanks from this newbie.

Comment: Intel's HD Graphics drivers are in the Linux kernel, so you don't need to track them down. The Acer Aspire 57337Z laptop  manual at https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/3680?b=1 does not show which graphics adapter you have. Therefore, would you mind running this: `sudo lshw | grep product | head -n1 && lspci -v -s $(lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1) ` then copy the result, click back here and click on [edit], and add the result to your question?